# UIWebView - Advertising banners on loading remote URL on Amazon

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, uiwebview, malware

My app shows an information page loaded from amazon s3 (a public html file). An user is experiencing this when using 3G data connection:
when loading this page, an advertising banner is being loaded over the official html code or the web view redirects to another web page.

How could this happen?
What is the proper way to prevent this unwanted situation?

Comment: Does this happen regarding the 3G connection provider?

Have you tried other connection (e.g. Domestic WiFi Hotspot)?
Does this happen with a specific provider?

Comment: It seems to be happening only using 3G connection. I can't reproduce this issue and this is happening just to one user, so I can't tell if it's affecting just one provider or more

Comment: some dirty plugin in the browser?

Comment: @TJ do you think that some dirty plugin installed on Safari is affecting app's UIWebView?

Comment: Do you use https for your connection ? It could be a MITM attack.